# Algorithm to extract elements with largest sum from a matrix without repeating rows or columns?

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

I have a numeric matrix, and I need to extract the set of elements with the largest possible sum, subject to the constraint that no 2 elements can come from the same row or the same column. Is there any efficient algorithm for this, and is there an implementation of that algorithm for R?

For example, if the matrix is (using R's matrix notation):

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    1    9
[2,]    8    4    2
[3,]    3    6    5
```

then the unique solution is `[1,3], [2,1], [3,2]`, which extracts the numbers 9, 8, and 6 for a total of 23. However, if the matrix is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6    2    1
[2,]    4    9    5
[3,]    8    7    3
```

then there are 3 equally good solutions: 1,8,9; 3,6,9; and 5,6,7. These all add up to 18.

Additional notes:

- If there are multiple equally good solutions, I need to find *all* of them. (Being able to find additional solutions that are *almost* as good would be useful as well, but not essential.)
- The matrix elements are all non-negative, and many of them will be zero. Each row and column will contain at least 1 element that is nonzero.
- The matrix can contain repeated elements.
- The matrix need not be square. It might have more rows than columns or *vice versa*, but the constraint is always the same: no row or column may be used twice.
- This problem could also be reformulated as finding a maximal-scoring set of edges between the 2 halves of a bipartite graph without re-using any node.
- If it helps, you may assume that there is some small fixed k such that no row or column contains more than k non-zero values.

If anyone is curious, the rows of the matrix represent items to be labeled, the columns represent the labels, and each matrix element represents the "consistency score" for assigning a label to an item. I want to assign the each label to exactly one item in the way that maximizes the total consistency.

Comment: So if the matrix is `m` x `n` with `m != n`, I suppose you want a sum of `min(m, n)` elements taken (otherwise you're forced to repeat a column or row)?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Also note that you can assume without loss of generality that `m <= n`, since the problem remains identical if you transpose the matrix.

Comment: If _all_ elements of the matrix are the same, any of `n!` ways produces the same result. Since in case of tie you want _all_ of them, there is nothing better than exponential brute force.

Comment: @user58697 Does it help if I can guarantee that each row and column only contains at most k non-zero elements for some small fixed k?

Comment: That would reduce worst case to `k!` ways. If this is acceptable, then again brute force it, perhaps.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Might a bit more exposition of the use case help, or is this just a general algorithm you are interested in?

Comment: @AllanCameron The problem is that I have a bunch of items with labels, but there is some uncertainty as to whether the labels are correct. So the elements of the matrix represent the result of a score function that measures how well a given label matches a given item, so a solution to the problem as described above will yield an assignment of labels to items that is most consistent given the scores in the matrix.

Comment: Some posts which may get you going: [Maximize sum of table where each number must come from unique row and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918741/maximize-sum-of-table-where-each-number-must-come-from-unique-row-and-column); [Finding The Max of sum of elements in matrix in distinct rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605840/finding-the-max-of-sum-of-elements-in-matrix-in-distinct-rows-and-columns); [Maximise sum of “non-overlapping” numbers from matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378738/maximise-sum-of-non-overlapping-numbers-from-matrix)

Comment: @Henrik Thanks! Those questions are definitely asking about an equivalent problem to mine. However, the main difference is that I'm looking for *all* solutions instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

My suggest would be to (1) find all the combinations of elements following the **rule** that in each combination, no two elements coming from the same row or same column (2) calculate the sum of elements in each combination (3) find the maximum sum and the corresponding combination.

Here I only show the square matrix case, the non-square matrix would follow similar idea.

(1) Suppose the matrix is n*n, keep the row order as 1 to n, all I need to do is to find all the permutations of columns index (1:n), after combine the row index and one permutation of columns index, then I would get the positions of elements in one combination that follow the **rule**, in this way I can identify the positions of elements in all the combinations.

```
matrix_data <- matrix(c(6,2,1,4,9,5,8,7,3), byrow=T,nrow = 3)
## example matrix

n_length <- dim(matrix_data)[1]
## row length

all_permutation <- permn(c(1:n_length))
## list of all the permutations of columns index
```

(2) Find sum of elements in each combination

```
index_func <- function(x){ ## x will be a permutation from the list all_permutation
  matrix_indexs <- matrix(data = c(c(1:n_length),x),
                         byrow = F, nrow = n_length)
  ## combine row index and column index to construct the positions of the elements in the matrix

  matrix_elements <- matrix_data[matrix_indexs]
  ## extract the elements based on their position

  matrix_combine <- cbind(matrix_indexs,matrix_elements)
  ## combine the above two matrices

  return(matrix_combine)
}


results <- sapply(all_permutation, sum(index_func(x)[,"matrix_elements"]))
## find the sums of all the combination
```

(3) Find the maximum sum and corresponding combination

```
max(results) ## 18 maximum sum is 18

max_index <- which(results==max(results)) ## 1 2 4 there are three combinations

## if you want the complete position index
lapply(all_permutation[max_index], index_func)

## output, first column is row index, second column is column index, last column is the corresponding matrix elements
[[1]]
         matrix_elements
[1,] 1 1               6
[2,] 2 2               9
[3,] 3 3               3

[[2]]
         matrix_elements
[1,] 1 1               6
[2,] 2 3               5
[3,] 3 2               7

[[3]]
         matrix_elements
[1,] 1 3               1
[2,] 2 2               9
[3,] 3 1               8
```

Comment: This looks like a working solution Xiang, but it's not very scalable. Even with a fairly small matrix of 10 * 10, there are 3.6 million permutstion vectors of length 10 to find and fit in memory. An exhaustive search is probably not the way to go here unless you have matrices with less than 100 elements.

Comment: @AllanCameron Note the comment above that points out that the absolute worst case always requires an exhaustive search. So there may not be any better solution in the general case.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson that's a clever observation, but it doesn't imply an exhaustive search as such, just an exhaustive generation of permutations. In fact, a simple check of whether all elements are equal followed by a return of the algorithmically generated set of permutations doesn't require any searching at all and might be a useful guard at the top of your function. Similarly, you would want an identity matrix treated as a special case without using exhaustive search. Maybe the best solution keeps brute force as a last resort?

Comment: @AllanCameron I do have some expectations about what a typical matrix will look like that I could use to implement some heuristic shortcuts, but the data is "noisy" enough that I can't relay on a set of heuristics covering every case, so if I want a fully general solution it looks like the worst case will always require an exhaustive search (or more likely, punting if the problem size becomes too large and the heuristics fail).

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 options:

1) Approaching this as an optimization problem where the objective function is to maximize the sum of elements chosen subject to the constraints that each row and column cannot be selected more than once.

sample data:

```
set.seed(0L)
m <- matrix(sample(12), nrow=4)
#m <- matrix(sample(16), nrow=4)
m

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    9    2    6
[2,]    4    5   11
[3,]    7    3   12
[4,]    1    8   10
```

code:

```
library(lpSolve)
nr <- nrow(m)
nc <- ncol(m)

#create the indicator matrix for column indexes
colmat <- data.table::shift(c(rep(1, nr), rep(0, (nc-1)*nr)), seq(0, by=nr, length.out=nc), fill=0)
#create indicator matrix for row indexes
rowmat <- data.table::shift(rep(c(1, rep(0, nr-1)), nc), 0:(nr-1), fill=0)
A <- do.call(rbind, c(colmat, rowmat))

#call lp solver
res <- lp("max",
    as.vector(m),
    A,
    rep("<=", nrow(A)),
    rep(1, nrow(A)),
    all.bin=TRUE,
    num.bin.solns=3)
```

sample output:

```
which(matrix(res$solution[1:ncol(A)], nrow=nr)==1L, arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   4   2
[3,]   3   3
```

2) 
And the above leads to an greedy heuristics approach to pick the largest element and eliminate the chosen row and column and then repeat on the smaller matrix:

```
v <- integer(min(nc, nr))
allix <- matrix(0, nrow=length(v), ncol=2)
for (k in seq_along(v)) {
    ix <- which(m == max(m), arr.ind=TRUE)
    allix[k,] <- ix
    v[k] <- m[ix]
    m <- m[-ix[1], -ix[2], drop=FALSE]
}
v
#[1] 12  9  8
```

But this does not lead to multiple solutions and hence not developing further to extract indices.