# Pythonic way to greedily find the 32 values in a numpy array that have the highest sum without repeating rows or columns and extract indices of values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, greedy

**EDIT: TLDR;How to finds 32 pairs of indices (i,j) in np array such that all i and all j are different and summing up the A[i,j] is as big as possible?** ~Thanks for clarifying Thomas

I'm realatively new to programming.

Suppose I have a np array of 566x566.

I have to find the 32 highest values without repeating rows or columns of a previously found value.
Afterwards I have to extract the indices of the values to backtrack the corresponding features.

I tried to do this with pandas aswell as numpy via finding the maxima of all columns, then extracting the indices of those and then discarding the rows and columns to build a smaller matrix. Then reiterating with the same method over that smaller matrix. But somehow it always fails because some of the functions are'nt iterable or there is a dumb Error etc...

I tried doing it with pandas/numpy because it would give me arguably the most concise code but honestly every method is more than welcome. Slicing the original array into lists and finding the highest values in there resulted in too much memory usage...

[pd_cosine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MInN.png)

'''python
for n in pd_cosine:
maxRow = pd_cosine.max(axis=n) #etc but the following code doesnt work aswell...
'''

I found a similar issue in R which was answered if that helps: [Algorithm to extract elements with largest sum from a matrix without repeating rows or columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62474441/algorithm-to-extract-elements-with-largest-sum-from-a-matrix-without-repeating-r)

Comment: Just to clarify, you want 32 pairs of indices `(i,j)` such that all `i` and all `j` are different and summing up the `A[i,j]` is as big as possible?

Comment: @Thomas Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do! Thanks for putting it into more concise terms!

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case (where the matrix is square), you can use `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` ([reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html?highlight=linear_sum_assignment#scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment)).

If you think of your rows as tasks, your columns as workers and your matrix entries as costs, `linear_sum_assignment` tries to find the assignment of tasks to workers such that the costs are minimized (or, in our case, maximized).

If performance is not crucial, you can simply use this algorithm and pick the 32 elements with the largest sum. However, this might be infeasible for larger matrices.

Here's how that could look like:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

A = np.random.rand(566, 566)

row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(A,maximize=True) # All elements for optimal assignment.
values_ind = A[row_ind, col_ind] # Get corresponding values.
ind_of_largest_32 = np.argsort(values_ind)[-32:] # Get the indices of the 32 largest elements.

row_ind_32 = row_ind[ind_of_largest_32]
col_ind_32 = col_ind[ind_of_largest_32]
values_ind_32 = A[row_ind_32, col_ind_32]
```

Then `row_ind_32` and  `col_ind_32` are the arrays with the distinct row and column indices for the 32 largest elements; `values_ind_32` contains the respective entries of `A`.

**Edit**: It works if `A` is non-square, too.

Comment: This is great!! Thanks for helping me out :)